# failed to convert string to negative number

Tags: python

let us suppose  that we have following  string :

```
text ="−4/−13"
```

and i want to extract first  number (-4), so i have split at / sign  and take first  element :

```
text_split =text.split("/")[0]
print(text_split)
```

i got result : −4 , of course  if  i want to convert this to the number  (negative), i should use simple logic :

```
negative_number =float(text_split[1:])*(-1)
print(negative_number)
```

but one thing what makes me confuse  is that  for text_split i can't find - sign, for instance when i type

```
print(text_split.find("-"))
```

i have got (-1) -which is stange because -4  actually contains - sign,  i have question : why it is so?

Comment: `text` contains Unicode minus sign (code point 0x2212), not ASCII hyphen (0x2d).

Comment: In the future, if you want to try to avoid this kind of problem, vscode has a feature to highlight unicode and ascii confusions.

Comment: If you just print the two characters next to each other you should see that they're different.

Comment: Or use `print(ord(text_split[0]))`

Comment: and  what is  ord for ascii - ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for "-", and the text does not contain this character. It contains "−". These are actually different characters, the shorter one is a hyphen, and the longer one is a minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

to Convert negative number you can use this

```
text ="−4/−13"
text_split =text.split("/")[0]
f=""
for i in text_split:
    if i=="−":
        continue
    print(i)
    f=f+i
    f=int(f)*-1
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on  recomendation  from users, i found following solution :

```
def get_temperature(month):
    temperature =month.split("/")[0]
    if ord(temperature[0])==8722  or  ord(temperature[0])==45:
        return float(temperature[1:]) *(-1)
    else:
        return float(temperature)
```

here is  full code which contains  output as well :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def get_temperature(month):
    temperature =month.split("/")[0]
    if ord(temperature[0])==8722  or  ord(temperature[0])==45:
        return float(temperature[1:]) *(-1)
    else:
        return float(temperature)
table = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota', match='Average daily maximum and minimum temperatures for selected cities in Minnesota')[0]
table.set_index("Location",inplace=True)
print(table.head())
table["July (°F)"]=table["July (°F)"].map(get_temperature)
table["July (°C)"]=table["July (°C)"].map(get_temperature)
table["January (°F)"]=table["January (°F)"].map(get_temperature)
table["January (°C)"]=table["January (°C)"].map(get_temperature)
print(table.head())
# average_table =table.mean(axis=1)
```

table before function :

```
         July (°F) July (°C) January (°F) January (°C)
Location                                                 
Minneapolis     83/64     28/18         23/7       −4/−13
Saint Paul      83/63     28/17         23/6       −5/−14
Rochester       82/63     28/17         23/3       −5/−16
Duluth          76/55     24/13         19/1       −7/−17
St. Cloud       81/58     27/14        18/−1       −7/−18
```

table after function :

```
             July (°F)  July (°C)  January (°F)  January (°C)
Location                                                     
Minneapolis       83.0       28.0          23.0          -4.0
Saint Paul        83.0       28.0          23.0          -5.0
Rochester         82.0       28.0          23.0          -5.0
Duluth            76.0       24.0          19.0          -7.0
St. Cloud         81.0       27.0          18.0          -7.0
```

thank you guys for help